# mysql Insert Bulk data from one to another table

Tags: mysql

nsert Bulk data from one to another table ,

master table

```
column1,col2,col3,col migrated
123      1    1     o
234      2   2       0
```

child table

```
col1,col2
123   1
234   2
```

if i get successful insert data from master table to child table ,i want to update master table migrated column to 1 or other wise i rollback my data from my child table using stored procedure with cursors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the need for stored procedures and such.  You can simply update across a join.

```
UPDATE master AS m
LEFT JOIN child AS c
  ON m.column1 = c.col1 AND
  m.col2 = c.col2
SET
  m.migrated = 1,
  c.col1 = m.column1,
  c.col2 = m.col2
```